# How to fetch all rows which don't have same value for a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to identify rows which don't have same value for a price column in a group of rows. for below example, i want to fetch grp2 trades from the table as price for row 7 is not matching with other rows in grp2.

I don't know before hand if there are any mismatches and in which group. Need to go over all rows in table and determine for mismatch and then fetch the records.
Below is just a sample data snippet.

| primary_id | price | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 99.00 | grp1 |
| 2 | 99.00 | grp1 |
| 3 | 99.00 | grp1 |
| 4 | 100.5 | grp2 |
| 5 | 100.5 | grp2 |
| 6 | 100.5 | grp2 |
| 7 | 100.55 | grp2 |

Comment: Try look into `DISTINCT` and/or `GROUP BY`. By reading your question I am also not sure whether you are looking for a simple `WHERE` clause, i.e. `WHERE group_id="grp2" AND primary_id=7`

Comment: what's your DB version?

Comment: I don't know before hand if there are any mismatches and in which group. Need to go over all rows in table and determine for mismatch and then fetch the records.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HAVING` clause along with `GROUP`ing `BY` price

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tab
 WHERE price IN (SELECT price
                   FROM tab
                  WHERE group_id = 'grp2'
                  GROUP BY price
                 HAVING COUNT(*)=1)
```

If your DB version is `8`, then prefer using `SUM()` window function in order to count what you want such as

```
SELECT primary_id, price, group_id
  FROM (
        SELECT t.*,
               SUM(group_id='grp2') 
               OVER (PARTITION BY price) AS count
          FROM tab AS t
       ) AS t
  WHERE count = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef9d16f2fc9f831c3a30b981399551f6)</kbd>